# Android how to have a Table Layout "refresh" based on realtime database value change on the same View

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to figure out how to have a Table layout be more "realtime" in displaying the values (with the backend being a Firebase Realtime Database)

I have the following Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<XList> xList;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Init List
        xList = new ArrayList<>();

        // Init with defaults
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            Box box = new Box(x, 0, "?");
            xList.add(x, box);
        }
     }
```

The above code initializes the list with "?" default.

When a user clicks a button the below code get triggered:

```
private void getXCoord() {
    coordRef.child("x").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot xSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String boxNum = xSnapshot.getKey();
                    Integer idx = xSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                    Box box = new Box(idx, 0, boxNum);
                    xList.set(idx, box);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {            
        }
    });
```

The above has a listener to the realtime DB to set the numbers as changes occur.

Lastly I have the code:

```
setContentView(new MainActivityLayout(MainActivity.this, xList));
```

Which calls my custom layout (MainActivityLayout) to add the values to a Table Layout

The MainActivityLayout code is as follows:

```
public class MainActivityLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    private Context context;
    private List<Box> xBox;
    TableLayout tableA;


    public MainActivityLayout(Context context, final List<Box> xCoord) {
        super(context);

        this.context = context;
        xBox = xCoord;

        // Init Table
        this.tableA = new TableLayout(this.context);           
        this.tableA.addView(this.componentTableRow());
    }


    TableRow componentTableRow() {
        TableRow componentTableRow = new TableRow(this.context);
        TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(150, 150);

        for (int x = 0; x < xBox.size(); x++) {
            headerImageView(xBox.get(x).xCoord());
            componentBTableRow.addView(params);
        }

        return componentBTableRow;
    }

    RelativeLayout headerImageView(String number) {
        RelativeLayout frameLayout = new RelativeLayout(this.context);

        TextView textView = this.headerTextView(number);
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);        
        textView.setLayoutParams(params);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);         
        frameLayout.addView(textView);

        return frameLayout;
    }
}
```

So now back to my question. With the code above how do I make the Table Layout update as the values change in the Firebase realtime D?

What am I missing!?

Comment: It looks like you have to call `refreshDrawableState` to [refresh the TableLayout](https://www.google.com/search?q=android+refresh+TableLayout+with+new+data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that did NOT work? Not sure why everyone is quick to the trigger to close a question and just point to another question when it hasn't been validated as the fix. I saw that previous question and the solution there didn't address my issue which is why i ported a "simular" question...

Comment: You need to force a refresh of the UI component after you change the data, and your code doesn't do that. If you tried using `refreshDrawableState` or some other way of doing that, show that in the code in your question. --- Note that the code you shared doesn't show how `getXCoord` is invoked, so we can't say how you're handling the asynchronous nature of this operation.  --- Finally: your `onCancelled` silently ignores errors. At its minimum, that should be `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {  throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that is why i asked the question, on what i am missing. I tried the `refreshDrawableState` and it does NOT work?!

Comment: "does NOT work" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. Do you have any errors? What is the exact behavior?